# Concatenating Location Codes to a User with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate the location codes a user is responsible for to the user's name with double semi colons as delimiters.

e.x.: Pete::1234::1235::1236::1237....

I think this can be achieved using a for loop, but I just can't quite get there. All help is appreciated.

Table-

| First Name | Last Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pete | Smith | 1234 |
| Pete | Smith | 1235 |
| Pete | Smith | 1236 |
| Pete | Smith | 1237 |

Comment: Great question. I envision it as a new column, maybe in a DataFrame, that holds the entire concatenation. Does that answer your question?

Comment: so given your example, the new column would have 4 x `Pete::1234::1235::1236::1237`? it would be clearer if you posted your desired output df

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? :

```
df.groupby("name")["location"].apply(lambda text : ''.join(text.to_string(index=False))).str.replace('(\\n)', '::').reset_index()
```

output:

```
   name                location
0  Pete  1234::1235::1236::1237
```

or as list :

```
df.groupby("name", as_index=False).agg({'location':list})
```

output:

```
   name                  location
0  Pete  [1234, 1235, 1236, 1237]
```